# How to avoid duplicate libraries when importing a Gradle project into IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

While importing a Gradle project with IntelliJ IDEA the resulting classpath contains different versions of multiple Java libraries.

How to avoid that?

[image]

Comment: i've had this happen to me, and the cause was that different "scopes" (configurations in gradle) were pulling in different versions of the same library, so intellij ended up having both versions of the library. the solution was to make sure (by way of exclusions and direct dependencies) that all configurations pulled the same versions of any affected library.

Answer (score 0):

If Gradle is doing that you probably should not prevented this unless you fully understand why it is doing so.

There are several reasons why multiple versions are necessary, for instance your build process has plugins that require different versions of a library.

One plugin could be developed by a vendor and other by a random team some place and they have different requirements. Some times even your own app could ask for that, like in cases where you are building components that may run in an environment with multiple class loaders, a classic example is OSGi.

Bottom line, if it is not interfering with your work, just leave them there, something requested that version. For your app itself, you are able to define your dependencies and have control of the required versions.

Normally depending on the authors of a lid a minor version number difference may signify huge API changes, and multiple versions are the only way to make the pieces fit together. Not necessarily only for your app, but also for your building. Not mentioning here the dependency inheritance that may add up.

Comment: Well no, my Gradle build correctly resolves dependency conflicts only including the latest version of each library. I'm a bit surprise IDEA is not doing that.

Comment: well, the IDE uses gradle. and having multiple versions is not always a conflict, having multiple might not be an error. you can eliminate the IDE with a simple experiment. with the ide closed, delete your gradle's cache, all libs it installed on your gradle home. then with a terminal you execute all tasks you normally need to run with gradle in a terminal, look at the cache for lib versions afterwards. your ide is probable using the same gradlle if you did not told it to do otherwise.